# specify last day of the month pandas .to_datetime()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Calling pd.to_datetime() with the following format option:

```
pd.to_datetime(single_price_listings['table_name'], format='%Y%m')
```

I have date in this column of the sort 201501, and would like to get 2015-01-31 rather than 2015-01-01 I'm not sure if I need a different format option or if I need some other pandas function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

pd.to_datetime(single_price_listings['table_name'], format='%Y%m') + MonthEnd(1)
```